# Magento file permissions nginx server issues error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I issued Magento recommended commands (given below) in the root directory of my Magento 1.9 installation and since then my nginx server is issuing 500 internal server error.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

I re-uploaded the files and website started to work but i can't figure out what's wrong with these commands!

Comment: why do you enter these commands if you dont understand them??  since when they became "recommended"??  dont read every word in magento docs, there are lots of crap....

Comment: I do understand them and I've figured out the solution too.. Now they became recommended because that's what Magento docs say and you've to trust the advice provided by the company that created the system. If you don't have anything on topic to say just keep your attitude to yourself please.

Comment: they only have created magento script, not the linux system....

Comment: one will assume that they know little something about linux and what permissions to set for magento to work on it.

Comment: for you this sounds strange, but this is exact mistake they have done few times in magento 1, and now they fixing the same mistake in magento 2.  for me as a system admin this inconsistency in manuals, in their code makes me sick :(

Comment: They'll learn some day :) 
Just so this post isn't a complete waste and someone might benefit from it, I've made some changes which should still maintain the permissions that Magento recommended, and will work with nginx.

find . -type f -exec chmod 440 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 550 {} \;
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;